# Expand and Contract

Tags: code-golf, number

Take a positive integer \$k\$ as input. Start with \$n := 1\$ and repeatedly increase \$n\$ by the largest integer power of ten \$i\$ such that \$i \le n\$ and \$i + n \le k\$.

Repeat until \$n = k\$ and return a list of all intermediate values of \$n\$, including both the initial \$1\$ and the final \$k\$.

During this process, growth will initially be limited by the former inequality, and only afterwards by the latter; the growth will take the form of an initial "expansion" period, during which \$n\$ is increased by ever-larger powers, followed by a "contract" period, during which \$n\$ is increased by ever-smaller powers in order to "zoom in" on the correct number.

### Test Cases

```
1 => [1]
10 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
321 => [1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
        10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90,
        100, 200, 300, 310, 320, 321]
1002 => [1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
         10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90,
         100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,
         1000, 1001, 1002]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: May we print the numbers instead of returning a list?

Comment: @Adám Yes, you may.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>72</strike> <strike>68</strike> <strike>64</strike> 63 bytes

```hs
f=(1!)
c!t|t==c=[c]|t>c=c:(c+10^(pred.length.show.min c$t-c))!t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfRCkAwFADQd19xVx62ZBlv6voRUbrGZGZxy4t/H@ftuOnerfcpLSiNUBkJfhmRsKfh5Y6QWkmFqUYZLztrb8PKTt/ufPSxBaCcS1JKcDqmvwjx2gJDDgs0tUkf)

Thanks Sriotchilism O'Zaic for -4 bytes!

#### Usage

```hs
f 321
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,310,320,321]
```

#### Explanation

```hs
c!t         -- c=current number, t=target number
 |t==c=[c]  -- Target is reached, return last number
 |t>c=c:(c+10^(pred.length.show.min c$t-c))!t
      c:                                        -- Add current number to list
                                min c$t-c       -- The minimum of the current number, and the difference between the current number and the target
                    length.show.                -- The length of this number
               pred.                            -- Minus 1
           10^(                          )      -- Raise 10 to this power
         c+                                     -- Add that to the current number
        (                                 )!t   -- Recursion
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer.

Comment: I'm still learning Haskell, there's probably room for improvement

Comment: I don't know Haskell, but maybe any of these tips might help: [tips for golfing in Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages). But I agree, nice answer. +1 from me.

Comment: PS: Minor error in your explanation: "_The **length of the** minimum of the current number, and the difference between the current number and the target_"

Comment: It's actually just the number itself (since smaller numbers have shorter length)

Comment: @PaulMutser Ah ok, I thought it was the length of the minimum (minus 1), due to the `pred.length`. When I ported your answer [to 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182588/52210) I used the `length-1` for the minimum number. EDIT: Ah, I see you indeed changed your explanation to that. :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Since `(^)` is higher precedence than `(+)` you don't need parentheses around the `(^)` expression.  Same goes for `(!)` and `(:)`

Comment: `pred.length.show.min c$t-c` can be shortened to `length(show.min c$t-c)-1`. Anonymous functions are acceptable, so you can drop the leading `f=` as explained in our [guide to golfing rules in Haskell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/56433).

Comment: Instead of guards, you can use only one case and a conditional: `c!t=c: if t>c then (c+10^(length(show.min c$t-c)-1))!t else []`. This allows to apply [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150792/56433) to save a few more bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfpmCrEPNfw1BRkytZscQ22Sq6oqbELlmnwkZXI1nb0CBOIyc1L70kQ6M4I79cLzczTyFZpUQ3WVPXUFNTsST2f24iUMhWoaAoM69EQUUhTcHYyPD/v@S0nMT04v@6Ec4BAQA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?[...f(n-(1+/(^10)?(0*$)/.exec(n)[2])),n]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc2xDoIwEADQ3a@4gYQ7bUuLmwaY/IqmBlKLQsjVgDEmhG@vxu1tb@ze3eLn4fmSHG8hpb7iqubGKqV6ZInmUODVaGpQ7zMqVPgEj0y2dESC3cm6dLZGgNECjuUfunQ71cf50vkHMlQ1@MhLnIKa4h3bbOUNpKwhW38DqTEOjDnktLVE6Qs)

### How?

#### Theory

The following steps are repeated until \$n=0\$:

- look for the number \$k\$ of trailing zeros in the decimal representation of \$n\$
- decrement \$k\$ if \$n\$ is an exact power of \$10\$
- subtract \$x=10^k\$ from \$n\$

#### Implementation

The value of \$x\$ is directly computed as a string with the following expression:

```
+---- leading '1'
|
1 + /(^10)?(0*$)/.exec(n)[2]
     \____/\___/
        |    |
        |    +---- trailing zeros (the capturing group that is appended to the leading '1')
        +--------- discard one zero if n starts with '10'
```

**Note**: Excluding the leading `'10'` only affects exact powers of \$10\$ (e.g. \$n=\color{red}{10}\color{green}{00}\$) but does not change the number of captured trailing zeros for values such as \$n=\color{red}{10}23\color{green}{00}\$ (because of the extra non-zero middle digits, `'10'` is actually not matched at all in such cases).

Comment: Ingenious noting you can do the iteration "backwards" keeping track of only one variable! It's a bit confusing that you use `k` for something completely different than in the challenge description (in fact your `n` is a mix of OP's `n` and `k` and your `x` is their `i`.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,n=1:n<k and[n]+f(k,n+10**~-len(`min(n,k-n)`))or[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVsnz9bQKs8mWyExLyU6L1Y7TQMopG1ooKVVp5uTmqeRkJuZp5Gnk62bp5mgqZlfBFTzv6AoM69EIU3DUJMLzjRAsI2NUCQMjDT/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>48</s> 41 bytes

```perl6
->\k{1,{$_+10**min($_,k-$_).comb/10}...k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX9cuJrvaUKdaJV7b0EBLKzczT0MlXidbVyVeUy85PzdJ39CgVk9PL7v2f3FipUKahqGmNReUZQBnGhshCxsYaVr/BwA)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
->\k{                                   }  # Anonymous code block taking k
     1,                             ...k   # Start a sequence from 1 to k
       {                           }       # Where each element is
        $_+          # The previous element plus
           10**      # 10 to the power of
                           .comb     # The length of
               min($_,k-$_)          # The min of the current count and the remainder
                                /10  # Minus one
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 30 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Prints numbers on separate lines to stdout.

```apl
{⍺=⍵:⍺⋄⍺∇⍵+10*⌊/⌊10⍟⍵,⍺-⎕←⍵}∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR7y7bR71brYD0o@4WENnRDuRrGxpoPerp0gdiQ4NHvfOBQjpASd1HfVMftU0A8mofdcww/J8G5vQBRT39H3U1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/pykYcunq6nIBaQMow9gIIWRgBAA)

`{`…`}∘1` anonymous infix lambda with 1 curried as initial \$n\$:

`⍺=⍵` if \$k\$ and \$n\$ are equal:

`⍺` return (and implicitly print) \$k\$

`⋄` else:

`⎕←⍵` print \$n\$

`⍺-` subtract that from \$k\$

`⍵,` prepend \$n\$

`10⍟` \$\log_{10}\$ of those

`⌊` floor those

`⌊/` minimum of those

`10*` ten raised to the power of that

`⍵+` \$n\$ plus that

`⍺∇` recurse using same \$k\$ and new \$n\$

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1[=ÐIαD_#‚ßg<°+
```

Port of [*@PaulMutser*'s (first) Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182584/52210), so make sure to upvote him!!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fMNr28ATPcxtd4pUfNcw6PD/d5tAG7f//jY2MAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6mj5F9aAuHo/DeMtj08ofLcRpd45UcNsw7PT7c5tEH7f@2hbfb/ow11DA10jI2MgZSBUSwA).

Outputs the numbers newline delimited.
If it must be a list, I'd have to add 3 bytes:

```
X[DˆÐIαD_#‚ßg<°+}¯
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9vc2FiaWX//1hbRMuGw5BJzrFEXyPigJrDn2c8wrArfcKv//8zMjM)  or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/f@IaJfTbYcnVJ7b6BKv/Khh1uH56TaHNmjXHlr/X@fQlv/RhjqGBjrGRsZAysAoFgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
1             # Push a 1 to the stack
 [            # Start an infinite loop
  =           #  Print the current number with trailing newline (without popping it)
  Ð           #  Triplicate the current number
   Iα         #  Get the absolute difference with the input
     D        #  Duplicate that absolute difference
      _       #  If this difference is 0:
       #      #   Stop the infinite loop
      ‚ß      #  Pair it with the current number, and pop and push the minimum
        g<°   #  Calculate 10 to the power of the length of the minimum minus 1
           +  #  And add it to the current number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
1µ«³_$DL’⁵*$+µ<³$Ð¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w0NZDqw9tjldx8XnUMPNR41YtFe1DW20ObVY5POHQ/v9ABQYGxgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 51 bytes

```
Union@NestList[#+10^Floor@Log10@Min[s-#,#]&,1,s=#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PzQvMz/PwS@1uMQns7gkWlnb0CDOLSc/v8jBJz/d0MDBNzMvulhXWUc5Vk3HUKfYFkj/DyjKzCtR0HdI13dQqDbUMTTQMTYCUQZGtf//AwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 131 bytes

```
@set/an=i=1
:e
@if %n%==%i%0 set i=%i%0
@echo %n%
:c
@set/an+=i
@if %n% leq %1 goto e
@set/an-=i,i/=10
@if %i% neq 0 goto c
```

Takes input as a command-line parameter and outputs the list of numbers to STDOUT. Explanation:

```
@set/an=i=1
```

Start with `n=1` and `i=1` representing the power of 10.

```
:e
@if %n%==%i%0 set i=%i%0
```

Multiply `i` by 10 if `n` has reached the next power of 10.

```
@echo %n%
```

Output the current value of `n`.

```
:c
@set/an+=i
@if %n% leq %1 goto e
```

Repeat while `i` can be added to `n` without it exceeding the input.

```
@set/an-=i,i/=10
```

Restore the previous value of `n` and divide `i` by 10.

```
@if %i% neq 0 goto c
```

If `i` is not zero then try adding `i` to `n` again.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>67</strike> 65 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
k=scan();o=1;i=10^(k:0);while(T<k)o=c(o,T<-T+i[i<=T&i+T<=k][1]);o
```

Pretty simple. It takes a set of powers of 10 beyond what would be needed in reverse order `i`.

(I would prefer to use `i=10^rev(0:log10(k))` instead of `i=10^(k:0)` since the latter is computationally ineffecient, but golf is golf!).

Then in a while loop, applies the conditions to `i` and takes the first (i.e. largest); updates `n`, and appends to output

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9u2ODkxT0PTOt/W0DrT1tAgTiPbykDTujwjMydVI8QmWzPfNlkjXyfERjdEOzM608Y2RC1TO8TGNjs22jAWqO2/JRD85wIA)

Comment: Save a byte using `T` instead of `n`; it should be 2 but I don't think that `TRUE` is acceptable output for `k=1`, so we set `o=+T`. [Try it!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9u2ODkxT0PTOt9WO8Q609bQIE4j28pA07o8IzMnVSPEJlsz3zZZI18nxEY3RDszOtPGNkQtUzvExjY7NtowFqjvvyUQ/OcCAA)

Comment: That is horrendous coding, I like it. incidently, I can set `o=1`, and get that second byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
1+«ạæḟ⁵«Ɗɗ¥Ƭ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//MSvCq@G6ocOm4bif4oG1wqvGismXwqXGrP///zEwMDI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 27 bytes

```
Wa>Po+:y/t*Y1Ty>o|o+y>ay*:t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PNEuIF/bqlK/RCvSMKTSLr8mX7vSLrFSy6rk////xkYmAA)

In pseudocode:

```
a = args[0]
o = 1
print o
while a > o {
  y = 1
  till y > o || o + y > a
    y *= 10
  o += y / 10
  print o
}
```

I'm pretty pleased with the golfing tricks I was able to apply to shorten this algorithm. By initializing, updating, and printing stuff in the loop header, I was able to avoid needing curly braces for the loop body. There's probably a golfier algorithm, though.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
ÆT±ApTmTnU)sÊÉÃf§U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xlSxQXBUbVRuVSlzysnDZqdV&input=MzIx)

```
ÆT±ApTmTnU)sÊÉÃf§U     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ                      :Map the range [0,U)
 T±                    :  Increment T (initially 0) by
   A                   :  10
    p                  :  Raised to the power of
     Tm                :    The minimum of T and
       TnU             :      T subtracted from U
          )            :    End minimum
           s           :    Convert to string
            Ê          :    Length
             É         :    Subtract 1
              Ã        :End map
               f       :Filter
                §U     :  Less than or equal to U
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>123</s> 122 bytes

```cs
m=>{var a=new[]{1}.ToList();int s;for(;(s=a.Last())<m;)a.Add(s+(int)Math.Pow(10,(int)Math.Log(s<m-s?s:m-s,10)));return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY0xa8MwEIX3/gphOtxhRdjpVlkOWTK50KHQoXS4OLKrwTLolGYQ@u2uPXXpULIc7z2@j@t517NbTlffN85H2TmOW2hbMZhlMm36piDIeHv7@Ex1Vm/zhgDqFRKshzmABjakOtpmbCaNpI6XC3AJK4MvFL/U63yDupK/QzePwM204wM/r1fWFSLqYOM1eEE6L/rhPbhoO@ctPBYppQFqVMdxDHakaKEQhQSSZzQtledyrZhzLvAvr7pTfNrf/7La/0tdfgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 142 bytes

```
L-D-M:-append(L,[D],M).
N-L-C-X-R-I:-I=1,C is X*10,N-L-C-C-R-1;D is C+X,(D<N,L-D-M,N-M-D-X-R-I;D>N,N-L-C-(X/10)-R-0;L-D-R).
N-R:-N-[]-0-1-R-1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY09D4IwFEV3fwVj0Xex1Y36MbQLCXRgakIYTCSGhAABE35@bdFJnd7LuefdN05DNzwwL61zOTSKFLdxbPo7y6nSNRVxsjHIoWBRIkuRnQWpqJ0juxWc3pHykZA6ULWzxPTJ0Frm88LP9VTqi/n4zO4Fjz3kMmjl@qNMYVDV4BChLnHXsNAytc@m61mQPOE/6CgOfzT@Bd0L)

Explanation coming tomorrow or something